# Reason for review suspension

Tags: support

I have been a member of the StackExchange group for a while now. I spend time checking the review queues to keep it clean from time to time. Recently, I found that I didn't have access to the reviews. I thought that could have been an error. However, I got the following message today:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again in 2 days.
> Being suspended can be a frustrating experience, but your help in moderation is still important. In the meantime, please read more about what review queues are and how they work.

And this was done without notifying me of any mistakes that might have happened by me while reviewing. So, it is as if sending a message that you may be kicked out any time we seem fit without giving you a reason. And we expect that you come back and provide reviews again without questioning? You were right in mentioning that this is frustrating. I may not spend my time in the review queues again unless I get the reason about the suspension in the first place.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions

Comment: It has been over a year without an answer. I am glad not to spend my time in the reviews here.

Comment: Probably no one knows (I don't), and it's better to be basked on https://meta.stackexchange.com/. It's their rule applying here I guess.